# Issue with Third-Party Cookies Blocked in Next.js Application Using Clerk Authentication

Tags: reactjs, next.js, clerk

I am following a youtube video "Build SaaS AI Platform with next.js 13, react, tailwind,prisma and stripe.
I am having problems with third party cookies being blocked. I have my landing page with a login and register button and when i click on them i get a 404 error saying the page cannot be found.

Comment: The 404 page sounds unrelated to the 3rd party cookies, i would suggest sharing your middleware.ts file contents and other code related to the sign-in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work at Clerk as a DevX Engineer
If that is the yellow warning in the console, it is entirely Clerk related it is a recent Chrome security update and the one of the services Clerk uses under the hood is the cause and it get surfaced as a "third party cookie blocked" warning. As long as the Web app is behaving as expected you can safely ignore them, the other service is aware and working on getting rid of those warnings, hope that helps :)